# Copy File from GCS to Drive

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I've written a Node function that reads a file from Google Cloud Storage and copies it to Google Drive. It is able to connect to GCS and create the file reference but fails when sending to Drive.

The error message says "NodeError: stream.push() after EOF"

Here's the relevant code snippet.

```
const file = bucket.file(fileName);

const fileMetadata = {
    'name': fileName
};

const readStream = file.createReadStream();

const media = {
    mimeType: "image/png",
    body: readStream
};

drive
    .files
    .create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: 'id'
    }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error', err)
        } 
    });
```

Comment: It seems that you can improve your code by creating a more complete read stream that can be directly piped into the write stream. Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/File#createReadStream), try this version and confirm whether this works for you.

Comment: I this the full error? If not can you share the whole error message.

Comment: I stumbled over the same issue. If I download the file from GCS to a temporary file and then upload this works fine. The direct download and upload to drive does not work.

I'm running the latest cloud storage library (1.7.0) and googleapi (32.0.0)

Here is the full stackdrive I get: https://pastebin.com/raw/0812WpZP